# angularjs same directive names conflict

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A noob question here. How do I avoid same directive names conflict when I'm using external modules. Currently I'm using the [angular bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) module, but downloaded another [module](https://github.com/Fundoo-Solutions/angularjs-carousel) just to use the carousel from there instead. They both have the same directive names `carousel` and its causing me problems if I include both these in my module.

```
var app = angular.module('text', ['fundoo.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

What would be the best solution for this?

Comment: I had the same issue with a custom directive called 'match' conflicting with one within angular boostrap. I renamed my directives with the prefix of the project to make sure they are unique.

Comment: [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) let's you build your own version with only the modules you need. Or simply rename the `carousel` directive to something else in either one of your libraries.

Comment: Can you clarify "causing me problems" ?

Comment: I don't understand why people can't namespace their directives when they make a library for other people to use. What is so wrong with the Angular UI people making `ui-carousel` instead of `carousel`? If everyone did this, software projects would have one less thing that could break. ^_^

Answer (score 5):

Actually all directive are executed, you may configure the order of execution with `priority` paramenter

> **Priority:**
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element, sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number. Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first. Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.

And you may also tell angular to stop the directive digestion in current element whenever you find a directive that has the `terminal` parameter setted to `true`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Still the soluction about creating priorities is a bit more complex to the problem, so i would stick to @nico 's soluction

and also, here's a plunker to test that angular executes both

http://plnkr.co/edit/e66I71UKp5mnurcjVzN4

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one name clash between directives, list the module with the carousel you want to use as the first dependency. From [my test](http://plnkr.co/edit/8fD4zMekVW9gl3Xmgb4U?p=preview) I conclude that additional directives with the same name are ignored (first one wins).

Answer (score 1):

If I'd were you **I'd use a prefix** for my own Angular directives/services/etc, that's what I've been doing lately and I don't have any clashing issues.

Alternatively, just rename the directive in question to something more verbose or specific.